# Get the sum of the column in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, row

Below is the table I have created, my goal is to get the sum of the value depending of each person has, and exclude any username duplicate.

```
username | value
Bob          5
Vicky        10
Bob          12
```

Desire results:

```
username | value
Bob          17
Vicky        10
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what the [**`GROUP BY`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) clause do, use `GROUP BY username` with `SUM(value)`:

```
SELECT username, SUM(value)
FROM tablename
GROUP BY username;
```

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9c358/2)

---

When you add a `GROUP BY` clause, rows that have the same values in the list of columns you specify in it, will be gathered into a group of unique values. For the other columns that are not listed in the `GROUP BY` clause, the aggregate function will be applied to it, the `SUM(value)` in the query above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT T.username, SUM(T.value) AS value
FROM your_table_name T
WHERE T.username IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY T.username
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This one

```
SELECT username, SUM(value) as val FROM tablename GROUP BY username;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following query:

SELECT `url`, SUM(pos) FROM `import_images` GROUP BY `url`